# trying to build my own vaadin widgetset library

Tags: vaadin

i have several applications that i need to write in vaadin.  im trying to put all of my custom components and widgetsets in one library, exactly the way vaadin does it, and simply include that library in my other projects.

I have my first widget in its library, maven compiles the library and the widget set correctly, but when i include it in my actual application, i get this

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for org.vaadin.jonatan.contexthelp.ContextHelp. 
Check its @ClientWidget mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. 
In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions. Unrendered UIDL:
-Unrendered UIDL
-org.vaadin.jonatan.contexthelp.ContextHelp(NO CLIENT IMPLEMENTATION FOUND) id=PID178 followFocus=false helpKey=112 hideOnBlur=true
-variables
selectedComponentId=
hidden=true
Complex field
```

why would it not be found?

Comment: I'm trying the same thing. Had set up project like in https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Component+Add-on+Project+Setup+HOWTO got snapshot and included in other projects. Works, but every time I change library I have to drop snapshot jar in a project. Do you know any better way to update lib?

Comment: Also did you recompile your application's widgetset after including lib?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't inherited from Vaadin default widget set in your widget set definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
  <inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet" />
   ...
```

Comment: i have that in my widgetset.gwt.xml